Did I draw my circuit diagram correctly for 2 MOSFETS and a solenoid?
My project consists of one 5 V solenoid (but uses 3.3 V), one voltage regulator (5 V to 3.3 V), one diode, two N-channel MOSFET transistors, and one 5 V LED strip, all controlled by a Raspberry Pi Zero. According to my power supply, the solenoid pulls 0.75 A at 3.3 V and the LED strip pulls 0.19 A.
Do I need another diode for the MOSFET connected to the solenoid? Since it's a logic level MOSFET I'm assuming it doesn't but for the sake of the diagram, do I?
Also this is my first time making a circuit diagram, please critique me if it looks wrong or I'm missing any valuable info!


Should that be IRLZ34?

Why are you only running the solenoid from 3.3V?

@TimWilliams actually it's supposed to be IRLZ44NPBF for it to be wide enough for the solenoid. I fixed the pic, sorry about that!

@Finbarr it gets really hot at 5V and the 3.3 is the min amount of voltage for it to move the same amount

D3 will turn on making the solenoid is active. It isn't really nessacary to the circuit so remove it or reverse it. The IRFZ34N probably has a bypass diode in it, so unless you are expecting a large current, remove D3

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but would I be wrong to assume that this circuit might not pull a large amount of current?

Depends on what the soleniod draws, what is the series resistance. (you also need to put in the series resistance)

So the resistance of the solenoid is R=V/I = 3.3/75mA = 44 ohms. For the series resistance, should I also add the diode?
